# Laravel маршрутизация без слеша

Tags: php, laravel

только начал изучать фреймворк и вот в чем вопрос: можно ли в роутинге указать Id без слеша?
То есть: не так test.ru/user/ { id } , а так: test.ru/user { id } ?

Comment: Самое просто это прочитать документацию по этому вопросу. И для теста, просто попробовать такой формат. Делов на 1 минуту и всё узнаете)

Comment: Спасибо) так и сделаю)